# Top Menu bar driving a sidebar sub menu

Tags: architecture, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an application written is `C#` `ASP.NET MVC 4` with `Razor` views.

I am a bit stuck on my menu structure.

[image]

As per the image above, one can see that there is a `Top Menu` and a `Side Menu`.

The standard menu bar that we all know has the logic that each `Menu Item` has sub items.

What I need is for the `Top Menu` to contain the `Menu Items`, then the sub items relevant to those items, to appear in the `Side Menu`.

The `Green` and the `Yellow` sections in the image above is part of my `_Layout.cshtml` page. The `White` section is where the `RenderBody()` happens.

As one would select the items in the `Side Menu`, the `White` section will get updated.

So my thinking was to have a `RenderSection` in the `_Layout.cshtml` that will render based on the view used. But my gut tells me there is a better approach.

Is it perhaps better to define those `Sub Menu Items` in the layout page as static, and just keep adding to it as new features come along? Or what is a better approach to load those elements dynamically?